# How to determine if screensaver is active on another session

Tags: command-line, screen-lock, screensaver

You can detect if a user's screensaver is active via:

```
gnome-screensaver-command -q
```

I'm trying to create a daemon to perform actions when the user is inactive, but I'm finding this command always returns false when not run from inside the user's session. For example, these variants all report the screensaver is inactive, even when it's active:

```
sudo gnome-screensaver-command -q
sudo -u myuser gnome-screensaver-command -q
```

Why is this, and how do I check the status of a user's screen from a different user like root?

Answer (score 3):

I know that it's a bit late but maybe some other people can read the answer now.

The problem is with dbus. You need to export the right variable before running the `gnome-screensaver-command`.

First you need to know the uid of the user. I exported also the `DISPLAY` of the user. You can get its value using the command `w`

```
sudo -u myuser DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS=unix:path=/run/user/$UID_OF_MYUSER/bus DISPLAY=:0 gnome-screensaver-command --query
```

This worked with Debian 9 and `gnome-screensaver-command 3.6.1`

Comment: This solved an older issue for me. Thank you.

Comment: This solution is also applicable for `cinnamon-screensaver-command -q`